# Solve equation with radicals.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve equation :  $\left(x-\dfrac{1}{6} \right)\sqrt{4x+1}+\left(x+\dfrac{1}{6} \right)\sqrt{1-2x}+\dfrac{7x+2}{x+2}=\left(x+1 \right)^{2}$.

Comment: this equation has $x=0$ is a root. but i can't slove it.

Comment: That just looks too bothersome.

Comment: @amWhy: no intention to hurt feelings, just to spur an edit, which was done.

Comment: I think it's an unfortunate language barrier: I try to trust that OPs are doing the best they can with English: many say less rather than more due to not trusting their ability to communicate well in English.

Comment: Also, the tag of "difference-equations" certainly does not apply.

Comment: @amWhy: yeah, probably a little insensitive of me.  I will put a little more thought into my snarks in the future.

Comment: @RonGordon I've done it too, (made a few somewhat insensitive "snark"s myself), but try to keep reminding myself of some of the barriers OP's face.

Comment: $\left(x-\dfrac{1}{6} \right)\sqrt{4x+1}+\left(x+\dfrac{1}{6} \right)\sqrt{1-2x}+\dfrac{7x+2}{x+2}=\left(x+1 \right)^{2}\\ \Leftrightarrow x\left(\sqrt{4x+1}+\sqrt{1-2x}-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{4x+1}+\sqrt{1-2x}}-x-2+\dfrac{6}{x+2}\right)=0$

Comment: Back to the subject, what are you supposed to use? I did a quick search at wolfram and, except for 0, it didn't had any exact solutions, just approximations, due to that when you expand it, you get a 10-degree equation.

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x-1%2F6%29*sqrt%284x%2B1%29%2B%28x%2B1%2F6%29*sqrt%281-2x%29%2B%287x%2B2%29%2F%28x%2B2%29%3D%28x%2B1%29%5E2

Comment: Apparently, I can't get the link to work properly in the comment, since it "breaks down" after the '*' character

Comment: @chubakueno have you tried putting it between brackets"()"? like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x-1%2F6%29*sqrt%284x%2B1%29%2B%28x%2B1%2%20F6%29*sqrt%281-2x%29%2B%287x%2B2%29%2F%28x%2B2%29%3D%28x%2B1%29%5E2)

Comment: (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x-1/6%29%2asqrt%284x%2b1%29%2b%28x%2b1/6%29%2asqrt%281-2x%29%2b%287x%2b2%29/%28x%2b2%29=%28x%2b1%29%5E2)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the validity of calculations of @chubakeno (thanks) and implicitly assuming that the tag algebra-precalculus implies that we are interested in real roots, the solution of equation can be fond. $x=0$ is root. Now we have $-\frac{1}{4}\leq x\leq\frac{1}{2}$. Using the Sturm's sequences which is correct for integer coefficients we obtain, that this polynomial (not considering $0$) has exactly $1$ root in the intervals $(-1/4,-1/8), (-1/8,-1/10),(1/4,1/3),(1/3,1/2)$. We can localize the roots more precisely if it is needed. Substituting back into the original equation we can decide (taking into account of error bounds) which one is root. If my (and computer :-) ) calculations are correct, then the only real solution is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

When you expand your equation to an ordinary polynomial, you get a quite ugly 10-degree expansion. I don't have any proof that says that this is irreducible, if I come up with some I will post it here. But meanwhile the only [solutions](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x-1/6%29%2asqrt%284x%2b1%29%2b%28x%2b1/6%29%2asqrt%281-2x%29%2b%287x%2b2%29/%28x%2b2%29=%28x%2b1%29%5E2) given by WA are 
$$x=0,\approx-3.05781-0.688252 i,\approx-3.05781+0.688252 i$$
The last two solutions come from the acceptable roots(to your equation) of the polynomial
$$36x^{10}+432x^9+2736x^8+8924x^7+15588x^6+22952x^5+26057x^4-17480x^3-1400x^2+800x+80 $$

Comment: With root : $x=0$ . I can find it easy .$\left(x-\dfrac{1}{6} \right)\sqrt{4x+1}+\left(x+\dfrac{1}{6} \right)\sqrt{1-2x}+\dfrac{7x+2}{x+2}=\left(x+1 \right)^{2}\\ \Leftrightarrow x\left(\sqrt{4x+1}+\sqrt{1-2x}-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{4x+1}+\sqrt{1-2x}}-x-2+\dfrac{6}{‌​x+2}\right)=0$

Comment: The problem we are having is to eliminate the roots in the expression inside the parentheses, for me, it is not so easy to get  it to work nicely with some algebraic/trigonometric substition